# Fill an array with rows that do not meet specific criteria and preserve hyperlink formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with 32 columns of data, starting in row 2 to LastRow.  The first row is a header row.  Several columns contain hyperlink formulas (“D”,”F”,”R”,”S”,”X”,”Z” and “AA”), other columns contain general values.  I would like to populate an array with rows that don’t include specific values in column D. Those values are part of a hyperlink formula.  For example, in D3 there is =HYPERLINK("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P35222"," CTNNB1"),  I’m filtering based on the values inside the second set of quotation marks “CTNNB1”.  I would like to output this array on a new sheet. The code bellow runs but it doesn’t output any data. The code includes comments to explain steps and issues. Please help me fix the code or suggest something that will work.  Thank you very much in advance.

Once the rows that meet the criteria are identified, how do I create an array row by row and how to correctly output it on a Sheet “Access”?

```
Sub aa()

Dim CellValue As Variant
Dim CellFormula As String
Dim CellPart() As String
Dim CellValueRow As Long
Dim CellValueCol As Long
Dim ColCrnt As Long
Dim ColLast As Long
Dim RowCrnt As Long
Dim RowLast As Long

With Worksheets("all")       ' Replaced with name of your worksheet

    RowLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ColLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    ReDim CellValue(1 To RowLast - 1, 1 To ColLast)  'max # of array rows based on last row of data available

    CellValueRow = 1

    For RowCrnt = 2 To RowLast
        CellFormula = .Cells(RowCrnt, "D").Formula
        If Left(CellFormula, 11) = "=HYPERLINK(" Then
            CellFormula = Mid(CellFormula, 12) '=> "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P42336","PIK3CA")
            CellFormula = Mid(CellFormula, 1, Len(CellFormula) - 1) '=> "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P42336","PIK3CA"
            CellFormula = Replace(CellFormula, """", "") '=> http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P42336,PIK3CA
            CellPart = Split(CellFormula, ",")
            'Debug.Print CellPart(0) & "  " & CellPart(1)

            If CellPart(1) <> "Q61R" And CellPart(1) <> "I391M" And CellPart(1) <> "V600E" And _
                CellPart(1) <> "PIC3CA" And CellPart(1) <> "BRAF" And CellPart(1) <> "EGFR" Then
                    CellValue(CellValueRow, ) = .Range(.Cells(RowCrnt, 1), .Cells(RowCrnt, ColLast)).Formula '===> need help here
                    CellValueRow = CellValueRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

   'For RowCrnt = 1 To 10
    'For ColCrnt = 1 To 10
       'Debug.Print "[R" & RowCrnt & "C" & ColCrnt & "]" & CellValue(RowCrnt, ColCrnt);
     'Next
    'Debug.Print
   'Next

End With

Worksheets("Access").Range("A2:AF" & RowLast).Value = Application.Index(CellValue, 0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1**

`Dim i, j, k, m, LastRow, openPos, closePos As Integer 'As Long`

This declares i, j, k to openPos as `Variants` and only closePos as an `Integer`,  If you list several variables in one `Dim statement`, you must give each one its own type.

Do not use type `Integer`.  With VBA, “Integer” declares a 16-bit integer which requires special processing on 32-bit or 64-bit computers.  `Long` is now the recommended type.

I rarely place several variables in a single `Dim statement`.  It saves a little typing but I prefer to declare my variables one per line in alphabetic sequence.

Please do not declare variables with names like i, j and k.  If this is a “quick write” macro that will then be discarded, names probably do not matter too much.  However, if you might return to this macro in six months, will you remember what i, j and k are?  Meaningful names take longer to type but make your code so much easier to read and understand.

**Issue 2**

```
With ActiveSheet
  LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

The active worksheet is the default worksheet so specifying its use does not serve much purpose.

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

would give exactly the same effect.

However I would prefer you write `With Worksheets(“xxxx”)`.  If you use the active worksheet, you are relying on the user having the required worksheet open when they start the macro.  If you return to this macro in six months, will you remember which worksheet is the required worksheet?  `Sheets.Add` makes the new sheet the active worksheet.  Your code can get very confusing if you have to remember which sheet is the active sheet.

**Issue 3**

`ReDim Result(LastRow - 1)`

The format for subscripts is: [*Lower* To] *Upper*.

If you omit “[*Lower* To]”, the value of the `Option Base statement` determines the value of the lower bound.  I do not recall ever seeing the `Option Base statement` but I still prefer being explicit.  VBA is unusual in allowing you to have different lower bounds; for most languages it is fixed as zero. With VBA I can write: `ReDim Result(2 To LastRow)`.  I always set my lower bounds to what every value I find most helpful at the time.

If VBA creates an array (for example with `Split`), that array will almost always have a lower bound of zero.  The only exception I can think of is when you copy a range to a Variant.  Here the resultant array has lower bounds of one.

You set `Result` to one dimension but use it as two dimensional array.  I think you want:

```
ReDim Result(1 To LastRow-1, 1 To 27)
```

**Issue 4**

`On Error Resume Next`

You should only use this statement like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Statement that might fail
On Error GoTo 0
If Err.Number > 0 Then
   Test or display Err.Number or Err.Description
End If
```

You should only use `On Error` when you cannot avoid Excel encountering an error.  For example, when opening a file for which you might not have read permission.  In this situation, `On Error` allows you to provide the user with a helpful message or perhaps recover by trying a different file.  You **do not** use it to avoid arithmetic errors.

**Issue 5**

```
If Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1 Then
  Str = .Cells(i, 4).FormulaR1C1
Else
  Str = .Cells(i, 4).Formula
End If
```

`Application.ReferenceStyle` affects how formulae are displayed. A VBA macro can request either style.  Pick the formula style you prefer although a hyperlink should not be affected by your choice.

**Issue 6**

Before you can extract the display text from a hyperlink formula you must check the cell contains a hyperlink formula.  This macro uses a different technique although there is nothing wrong with searching for the last two double quotes in the formula.  With this technique, the value you seek is in `CellPart(1)`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()

  Dim CellFormula As String
  Dim CellPart() As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  With Worksheets("Data")       ‘ Replace with the name of your worksheet
    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For RowCrnt = 2 To RowLast
      CellFormula = .Cells(RowCrnt, "D").Formula
      If Left(CellFormula, 11) = "=HYPERLINK(" Then
        ' It is possible to make all these changes to CellFormula in one go
        ' but this is better for showing what I am doing
        CellFormula = Mid(CellFormula, 12)
        CellFormula = Mid(CellFormula, 1, Len(CellFormula) - 1)
        CellFormula = Replace(CellFormula, """", "")
        CellPart = Split(CellFormula, ",")
        Debug.Print CellPart(0) & "  " & CellPart(1)
      End If
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

**Issue 7 **

In your macro you are:

- Scanning down column D looking for rows of interest.
- Copying the cells of rows of interest to an array.

You do nothing with the final array but I assume you intended to write it to the new worksheet.

This technique involves moving every cell of interest individually from the worksheet to the array.  This is not quite as slow as some people think but it is not in my view the easiest approach.

You have used `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` to find the last row containing data.  VBA offers several methods of finding the last row and column and this is generally the easiest to use.  However, none of the available methods works in every situation.  This technique relies on the programmer knowing which column (or row) contains the most data.

I have used:

```
RowLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
ColLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
```

The first statement finds the last used cell in any column while the second finds the last used cell in any row.  These statements do not rely on the programmer knowing which column has the last row or which row has the last column.  They are also useful if your data is not rectangular.

In this macro, I have pulled every formula from every cell in the worksheet into an array in a single statement.  I have then displayed the first ten rows and columns so you can see what I have imported.

```
Sub Demo2()

  Dim CellValue As Variant
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  With Worksheets("Data")       ' Replace with the name of your worksheet

    RowLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ColLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    CellValue = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowLast, ColLast)).Formula

    For RowCrnt = 1 To 10
      For ColCrnt = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print "[R" & RowCrnt & "C" & ColCrnt & "]" & CellValue(RowCrnt, ColCrnt);
      Next
      Debug.Print
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

You may need to increase my end values of 10 to see enough data but this macro demonstrates that I can download every value and formula in a worksheet into an array with a single statement.

I recommend creating little macros like mine that explore a single feature when you are unsure about that feature.  The trouble with your complete macro is that you do not know where it has gone wrong.  With a single feature macro there is nothing else to confuse the picture as you try different things you get it working.  If you fail to get it working, a single feature macro will get an answer on Stack Overflow much more quickly than a confused, multi-feature macro.

**Complete solution**

Above I have explored how to access the data and how to make decisions about which rows are of interest.  I think we are now ready to make final decisions.

There are several approaches and it is not obvious to me which would be the better.

For step 1, I believe importing the worksheet into an array and identifying interesting rows in memory is the best approach.  The alternative, reading down column D within the worksheet, has no advantages that I can see.

For step 2, I can see three different approaches with a minor different to step 1:

1. Copy the entire worksheet to an array.  Copy interesting rows to a different array.  Copy the second array to a new worksheet.
2. Copy column D of the worksheet to an array.  Use the array to identify interesting rows.  Copy the interesting rows, as they are identified, from the original worksheet to a new worksheet.
3. Copy column D of the worksheet to an array.  Use the array to identify interesting rows.  Use `Union` to a single range containing all the interesting rows and copy them as a unit from the original worksheet to a new worksheet.

I have never tried approach 3 although I have done something similar by using `AutoFilter` to select rows and then copying the visible rows to a new location.  However, I do not see that it offers anything over approach 2 and I have had problems with very large unions so I have ignored approach 3.

You can only copy values and formulae to an array so you will lose any formatting with approach 1.  Approach 1 is probably faster than approach 2.  Approach 2 looks as though it will be a little simpler to code.

Apart from the possible need to preserve formatting, I cannot see a major advantage for either approach.  Since formatting might be important for this or a similar project, I have decided to go for approach 2.

It is not relevant for approach 2, but you say you do not know how to `ReDim Preserve` Result to remove the unused rows.  The answer is you cannot remove these rows conveniently but it does not matter.  You can only use `ReDim Preserve` to change the size of the last dimension of an array.  An array read from a worksheet or being prepared for writing to a worksheet has the worksheet columns as the second dimension.  You could use the worksheet function `Transpose` to switch the dimensions, `ReDim` the array and then `Transpose` back.  However, I have found that some (perhaps all) worksheet functions are very slow.  A transpose coded in VBA is faster than the Excel version.  The worksheet functions seem perfectly adequate when called from the keyboard, so the slowness is probably an overhead of the interface.  However, when writing an array to a worksheet, unused trailing rows do not matter except possibly if they might overwrite rows you wish to keep.

The following is my attempt at your macro.  I do not have much suitable test data but it appears to work as required.

```
Sub NewAa()

  ' Change these names as required
  Const WshtSrcName As String = "Data"
  Const WshtExtName As String = "Extract"

  Dim CellFormula As String
  Dim CellPart() As String
  Dim CellValue As Variant
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim InxNTBE
  Dim NotToBeExtracted() As Variant
  Dim RowExtCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet
  Dim WshtExt As Worksheet

  ' If you are going to be extracting different hyperlinks, an array is easier
  ' to amend than an If statement
  NotToBeExtracted = Array("Q61R", "I391M", "V600E", "PIC3CA", "BRAF", "EGFR")

  Set WshtSrc = Worksheets(WshtSrcName)

  Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
  ' The new worksheet is now the active worksheet
  ActiveSheet.Name = WshtExtName
  Set WshtExt = ActiveSheet

  With WshtSrc

    RowSrcLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    ' Import column D
    CellValue = .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(RowSrcLast, "D")).Formula
    ' CellValue will be an array with dimensions (1 To RowLast, 1 to 1).
    ' Note the lower bounds for such arrays are always one even when column 4 has been imported.

  End With

  ' Copy header row
  WshtSrc.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=WshtExt.Cells(1, 1)
  ' Note the format of copy range is: Xxxxx.Copy Destination:=Yyyyy
  ' where:
  '   Xxxxx is the range to be copied
  '   Yyyyy is the top left cell of the destination range
  '   "Destination:=" is optional but  think it add clarity.

  RowExtCrnt = 2

  For RowSrcCrnt = 2 To RowSrcLast

    CellFormula = CellValue(RowSrcCrnt, 1)
    If Left(CellFormula, 11) = "=HYPERLINK(" Then
      ' Format is: =HYPERLINK("Xxxx","Yyyy")
      ' Extract Yyyy to CellPart(1)
      CellFormula = Mid(CellFormula, 12)
      CellFormula = Mid(CellFormula, 1, Len(CellFormula) - 1)
      CellFormula = Replace(CellFormula, """", "")
      CellPart = Split(CellFormula, ",")
      ' Attempt to match CellFormula against one of the hyperlink texts
      ' that are not to be extracted
      Found = False
      For InxNTBE = LBound(NotToBeExtracted) To UBound(NotToBeExtracted)
        If CellPart(1) = NotToBeExtracted(InxNTBE) Then
          Found = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If Not Found Then
        ' This hyperlink is to be extarcted
        WshtSrc.Rows(RowSrcCrnt).Copy Destination:=WshtExt.Cells(RowExtCrnt, 1)
        RowExtCrnt = RowExtCrnt + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tony,  I really appreciate the feedback looking forward to more helpful feedback tomorrow.

Comment: Hello Tony, I've implemented your suggestions (see revised code above) but still need help with populating the Cellvalue array with rows that meet the criteria.  My code wrongly populates the Cellvalue array with a single row of data. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @user3781528.  Sorry Sunday was busier than I expected and I had no time to complete my answer. I have now posted the remainder of my answer.